# How to iterate through an array to return a template literal for each element?

Tags: javascript

Given an array of 7 temperature values, how can I return a statement such as "15 degrees in one day, 10 degrees in 2 days, etc.)?

```
let weather = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30];
for (i=0; i<weather.length; i++) {return `${weather[i]} in ${weather.findIndex(i)} days`};
```

Comment: Group by, then loop over the values

Comment: If you want to map your array of temperatures to an array of output strings, use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Explain your expted output. How should "15 degrees in one day" and "10 degrees in 2 days" be generated? `15` is the forth element, how do you expect to associate that with "one day? Same for 10. Its the third element, why should that be in 2 days?

Answer (score -1):

Is this perhaps what you are looking for?
[Atob / btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa)
Here is the version with offending characters escaped, each sequence \xNN should count 1

```js
let weather = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30];
for (let i=0; i<weather.length; i++) {
    console.log(`${weather[i]} degrees in ${btoa("×C§{Dð£Dá­ç´\x16\x8b«ÐX¯{D¢ÇD\x9e½éô\x12(!·Cb\x9dí").split(0)[i+1]} days`);
};
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but perhap because the output did not match OPs expected output? But "15 degrees in one day, 10 degrees in 2 days" makes no sense for me... So dunno whats wrong. I think OP should explain the desired output to clarify that.

Comment: maybe he just gave a quick example of what he wants but he was using the index of the element to tell in how many days til the temperature, so I made an example using his data where 10 is the 3rd element and 15 is the 4th. If he can clarify what he needs then I can edit my answer